# Почему элементы не выводятся по порядку?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct element
{
string data;
element *adress;
};

class List
{
      private:
              element *StartAdress, *FinishAdress;

      public:
               List()
               {
                     StartAdress = NULL;
                     FinishAdress = NULL;
               }

void ElAdd (string a)
{
 element *e;
 e = new element;
 e -> data = a;
 e -> adress = StartAdress;
 StartAdress = e;
}

void print()
{     
 element *e;
 for (e = StartAdress; e != NULL; e = e -> adress)
 cout << e -> data << " " << endl;
}
};
```

Создал список. Но как известно в списке все вводится и выводится в том же порядке. Но у меня наоборот. Т.е ввожу 1, 2, 3, а он выводит 3, 2, 1. Как это исправить? Сам не справился, поэтому прошу помощи. Хочу чтобы как вывел (1, 2, 3) чтоб так и выводил (1, 2, 3). Где ошибка в коде?

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, создав новый элемент, его адрес Вы присваиваете полю StartAdress. Вам нужно менять FinishAdress, добавив новый элемент в хвост списка, а значение полю StartAdress присвоить один раз при создании первого элемента. Тогда же при создании первого элемента, указателю FinishAdress присвойте StartAdress, чтобы, если в списке присутствует только один элемент, указатели начала и конца совпадали.

Во-вторых, при добавлении нового (но не первого) элемента пишите

```
FinishAdress->adress = e;  
FinishAdress = e;
```

Ваш нынешний код изначально строит список в обратном порядке, т.е. добавляя элемент, Вы ставите его в начало. При это связь такова, что каждый элемент списка у Вас указывает на предыдущий, а не на следующий. Потому при обходе, начиная с StartAdress, Вы и получаете обратный порядок.

В итоге код добавления элемента будет содержать

```
// Создаем новый элемент
element *e;  
e = new element;  
e -> data = a;

// Корректно обрабатываем ситуацию, когда список пуст  
if (StartAdress == NULL) {  
    StartAdress = e;  
} else {  
    FinishAdress->adress = e;  
}

// Модифицируем хвост      
FinishAdress = e;  
FinishAdress->adress = NULL;
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: @navi1893, по сути дела Вы запрограммировали структуру данных, которая называется **стек**.